# sharing a button variable between two files

Tags: javascript, iphone, variables, titanium, global

I have a button which when clicked opens up a modal window with additional share functionality. Everything works fine on Android, but I have a small issue with iOS. I am able to share a variable which is just a number, but not the variable which is a button. Code below from main app.js:

```
var shareBtn2;
var fullScore;
shareBtn2.addEventListener('singletap', function (e){

    shareBtn2.setBackgroundImage('share_pressed.png');

    var shareModal = require('shareModal');
    var shareModalView = new shareModal();
    Ti.App.myGlobalVar=shareModalView;
    win2.add(shareModalView);

    if (DJBool){
        Ti.App.fireEvent('shareModalEvent', {
              myBtn: shareBtn2,
              myPts: Math.round(fullScore)
        });
        alert('Was a DJBool');
    }
```

and then in my second file which contains 4 buttons to share via, fb, twitter, email and a cancel button.

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('shareModalEvent', function(event) {
    globalPts=event.myPts;
    globalBtn=event.myBtn;
    alert('received share modal event');
});

console.log(typeof globalPts);//outputs number
console.log(typeof globalBtn);//outputs undefined
```

The only reason I need this button in my second file is if the user presses the 'cancel button' in the second file, I want to change the backgroundImage of my shareBtn to it's original state. i.e.

```
cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e){
        cancelBtn.setImage('cancelShare_pink.png');
        win2.remove(Ti.App.myGlobalVar);
        globalBtn.setBackgroundImage('share.png');

    });
```

Hope I have been clear.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't pass round Ti.UI objects in events, only primitives (like strings, numbers) in IOS but it worked on Android. In he end I wrote another custom event to solve the issue